# How does gdb (Thumb-2) know where the top of the stack is?

Tags: arm, gdb, stack-trace, cortex-m

GDB attached to my Cortex-M3 code is giving me stack traces that look like this:

```
#0  0x00000992 in zeptos_mod_svc ()
#1  0x00000d36 in Uart_ReadChar (uart=3) at src/zeptos/drivers/uart.c:60
#2  0x00000d6c in gsmgps_entry () at src/vectr/gsmgps.c:13
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

They're useful, but I'd like to Do The Right Thing and eliminate that final entry. What is GDB looking for to signal the top of the stack, and what should I place on the stack of new tasks that I create to help it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to terminate the stack in DWARF CFI information.

For ARM in particular, gas supplies a ".cantunwind" directive to do this.  On other architectures I think it's more normal to use cfi_undefined to mark the frame pointer.